# python customtkinter my frame as a default square i cannot remove

Tags: python, customtkinter

i used ctk to create a panel that has round corners and a dark gray color
unfortunately i can see a square which i thought was the background. this square is overlaps my
stuff and is really ugly. i don't know how to remove it any ideas ???
[image: here's a screenshot]

i tried making a panel smooth in the corners, the frame's default square is still here.
i can't think of anything to remove it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You cannot remove this square as it is the canvas on which the frame is drawn. And a canvas can not be transparent in tkinter.

Comment: it is not a canvas but it is in fact a frame